# Lazy loading VS Eager loading in Active record - Rails

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

When reading in forums, for query optimization eager loading is better than lazy loading in active record usage. But when I attend interviews people tell that lazy loading is useful in some scenarios. When I surfed in google I can't find enough information about it. Can anybody guide me to understand this concept. Lazy loading Vs Eager loading

**My understanding:**
Eager loading solves N+1 query problems when retrieving associated records.

Kindly give me some practical scenarios

Answer (score 3):

**When Lazy loading is needed?**

You want to retrieve data of any model with conditions (join conditions) of other associated models but you do not want to load those associated table data which can consume time.

So lazy loading will save time as you can get data by filtering but you do not load associated data from database.

**When eager-loading is needed?**

You want conditions or no conditions but you are calling their associated records also so it is good to load associated records eagerly. So calling associated records on object do not fire query on database each time for each objects.

Suppose,

@users is `ActiveRecord::Relation` collection object (has_one :id_card) having size 80 & I called each loop for table as below,

```
@users.each do |user|
  user.id_card.name
end
```

It will fire query 80 times on IdCard model table. So here is it efficient.

**Update**

`includes` do not create two separate queries always, read [here](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/01/24/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where).

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me some practical scenarios for both u have gone through in your peojects

Comment: `User.includes(:id_card)` will load both `users` & `id_cards` table records, but this is not same case for `joins`

Comment: I updated answer with one of the useful reference, please check.